# i want to do server side grouping in this code how can i do server side grouping and pivot from backend

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am implementing an ag-grid from the server side. I have implemented the first three basic steps in the code I have implemented pagination searching and ordering from the backend for ag-grid I want to grouping from the backend and pivoting from backend how can I do this code in this code? if you have any suggestions to implement

```
@Service
public class CompanyService {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public Page<CompanyResponse> getCompanies(Pageable pageable, RequestWithFilterAndSort requestWithFilterAndSort){
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder=entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<CompanyResponse> companyResponseCriteriaQuery=criteriaBuilder.createQuery(CompanyResponse.class);
        Root<Company> companyRoot=companyResponseCriteriaQuery.from(Company.class);

        companyResponseCriteriaQuery.multiselect(companyRoot.get("id"),
                companyRoot.get("companyName"),
                companyRoot.get("employeeName"),
                companyRoot.get("description"),
                companyRoot.get("leave")
                );

        if(requestWithFilterAndSort.getColId()!=null && requestWithFilterAndSort.getSort().equals("desc")){
            companyResponseCriteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(companyRoot.get(requestWithFilterAndSort.getColId())));
        }
        else if(requestWithFilterAndSort.getColId()!=null && requestWithFilterAndSort.getSort().equals("asc")){
            companyResponseCriteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(companyRoot.get(requestWithFilterAndSort.getColId())));
        }

        List<Predicate> predicateList=new ArrayList<>();
        predicateList.addAll(getFilter(criteriaBuilder,predicateList,companyRoot,requestWithFilterAndSort));
        Predicate predicateArray[]=new Predicate[predicateList.size()];

        companyResponseCriteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicateList.toArray(predicateArray)));

        List<CompanyResponse> companyResponseList=entityManager.createQuery(companyResponseCriteriaQuery).getResultList();
        List<CompanyResponse> companyResponses=entityManager.createQuery(companyResponseCriteriaQuery).
                setFirstResult((int) pageable.getOffset()).
                setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize()).
                getResultList();
        return new PageImpl<>(companyResponses,pageable,companyResponseList.size());
    }

    private List<Predicate> getFilter(CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder,List<Predicate> predicateList,Root<Company> companyRoot,RequestWithFilterAndSort requestWithFilterAndSort){
        Optional.ofNullable(requestWithFilterAndSort.getFilterModel()).ifPresent(filterModelMap->{
            for(Map.Entry<String, FilterModel> filterModelEntry:filterModelMap.entrySet()){

                String colName=filterModelEntry.getKey();
                FilterModel filterModel=filterModelEntry.getValue();
                System.out.println("colName in filter : "+colName);
                /*if(filterModel.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("NUMBER") && filterModel.getFilterType().equalsIgnoreCase("GREATETHEN")){
                    predicateList.add(criteriaBuilder.ge(companyRoot.get(colName),Long.parseLong(filterModel.getFilter())));
                }
                else if(filterModel.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("NUMBER") && filterModel.getFilterType().equalsIgnoreCase("LESSTHEN")){
                    predicateList.add(criteriaBuilder.lessThan(companyRoot.get(colName),Long.parseLong(filterModel.getFilter())));

                }*/
                if(filterModel.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("equals")){
                    predicateList.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(companyRoot.get(colName),filterModel.getFilter()));
                }
                else if(filterModel.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("notEqual")){
                    predicateList.add(criteriaBuilder.notEqual(companyRoot.get(colName),filterModel.getFilter()));

                }
                else if(filterModel.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("contains")){
                    predicateList.add(criteriaBuilder.like(companyRoot.get(colName),filterModel.getFilter()));

                }
                else if(filterModel.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("notContains")){
                    predicateList.add(criteriaBuilder.notLike(companyRoot.get(colName),filterModel.getFilter()));

                }
                else if(filterModel.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("startsWith")){
                    predicateList.add(criteriaBuilder.like(companyRoot.get(colName),"%"+filterModel.getFilter()));

                }
                else if(filterModel.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("endsWith")){
                    predicateList.add(criteriaBuilder.like(companyRoot.get(colName),filterModel.getFilter()+"%"));
                }
                else if(filterModel.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("blank")){
                    predicateList.add(criteriaBuilder.isNull(companyRoot.get(colName)));
                }
                else if(filterModel.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("notBlank")){
                    predicateList.add(criteriaBuilder.isNotNull(companyRoot.get(colName)));
                }
            }
        });
        return  predicateList;
    }
}
```